# Regex to match a string with 2 letters only in which at least 1 is lowercase

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a RegEx that checks to see if there are exactly 2 letters in which at least 1 (and maybe 2) are lowercase.

I used the RegEx of `(?=.*[a-z])` which correctly lets me know if one character is lower case but can't figure out how to make it also check that there are exactly two letters. Let me know if anyone has any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` and `$` anchors to match the ends of the string, so you can restrict the number of characters in the entire string.

Then use simple alternation to test for the first or second character being lowercase.

```
^(?:[A-Za-z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Za-z])$
```

Comment: I tested this out and it works great. Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z]{2}$
```

`(?=.*[a-z])` is a *positive lookahead* that requires there to be at least one lowercase letter. `[A-Za-z]{2}`, together with the start-of-string and end-of-string anchors (`^` and `$`), ensures the string contains two letters.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dh7QcL/1)